# Como obtengo el Uri de un archivo que esta en la memoria interna en Android

Tags: java, android

lo que quiero es poder sacar el Uri para pasárselo a otra función pero perece no funcionar ninguna forma

estoy creando una app que usa el sdk de OneDrive, el cual proporciona este ejemplo **ejemplo de subir archivos**

```
private void upload(final int requestCode) {
    //mensajeToast("Entro al uploat "+mItemId);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setType(ACCEPTED_UPLOAD_MIME_TYPES);
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

**Cuando recibe el objeto** en el onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {

    final BaseApplication application = (BaseApplication) this.getApplication();

    final IOneDriveClient oneDriveClient = application.getOneDriveClient();

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIMPLE_UPLOAD
            && data != null
            && data.getData() != null
            && data.getData().getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase(SCHEME_CONTENT)) {

        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle(R.string.upload_in_progress_title);
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.upload_in_progress_message));
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setProgressNumberFormat(getString(R.string.upload_in_progress_number_format));
        dialog.show();
        final AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> uploadFile = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {

                try {

                    final ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                    final ContentProviderClient contentProvider = contentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(data.getData());
                    final byte[] fileInMemory = FileContent.getFileBytes(contentProvider, data.getData());
                    contentProvider.release();

                    // Repara el nombre del archivo (necesario para las fotos del carrete de la cámara, etc.)
                    final String filename = FileContent.getValidFileName(contentResolver, data.getData());

                    final Option option = new QueryOption("@name.conflictBehavior", "fail");
                    oneDriveClient
                            .getDrive()
                            .getItems(mItemId)
                            .getChildren()
                            .byId(filename)
                            .getContent()
                            .buildRequest(Collections.singletonList(option))
                            .put(fileInMemory,
                                    new IProgressCallback<Item>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void success(final Item item) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                              mensajeToast("Archivo subido "+item.name);

                                            //refresh();
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void failure(final ClientException error) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                            if (error.isError(OneDriveErrorCodes.NameAlreadyExists)) {
                                                mensajeToast("Hay conflicto con el nombre de otro archivo ");
                                            } else {
                                                mensajeToast(application.toString());
                                                mensajeToast(error.getMessage());
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void progress(final long current, final long max) {
                                            dialog.setProgress((int) current);
                                            dialog.setMax((int) max);
                                        }
                                    });
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.toString());
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        uploadFile.execute();
    }
}
```

**Todo eso funciona bien**

Ahora lo que quiero es subir ese archivo sin darle la posibilidad de escoger el archivo si no que yo lo escoja y lo suba

**Mi codigo esta asi**

```
private void subirCopia(){

    //guardo un archivo de prueba para subirlo
    OutputStreamWriter escritor, escrito = null;
    String nomb = "1002";
    try {
        //creo la cabezera con mode_apped
        escrito = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(nomb + ".txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
        escrito.write("Para preparar la importacion de instorial" + "\r\n");
        escrito.close();

        Toast.makeText(this, "REGISTRADO EL TXT PRUEBA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Instorial no pudo ser registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //Inicio el codigo para subir
    final BaseApplication application = (BaseApplication) this.getApplication();
    final IOneDriveClient oneDriveClient = application.getOneDriveClient();

    String name = "1002";
    String conten = "content"; //ni idea pero lo tiene el otro codigo al empezar el Uri, creo que es para comprobar que si es el archivo que se pidio
    //este es el uri que recogio el otro codigo con el onActivityResult en el bloque de codigo recogido de la memoria externa
    //final Uri ruta = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents./document/primary%3APrestaCOP%2F1002.txt");
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory(); //enlace a la memoria interna
    String origen = data+"/data/com.example.andresperezmelo.onedriveejemploanalizes/files/" + name + ".txt";

    final File archivo = new File(data, origen);

    final Uri ruta = Uri.fromFile(archivo);

    mensajeToast("Uri del archivo "+ruta);

    Log.d("entro linea 426","426 linea");
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.upload_in_progress_title);
    dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.upload_in_progress_message));
    dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    dialog.setProgressNumberFormat(getString(R.string.upload_in_progress_number_format));
    dialog.show();
    final AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> uploadFile = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {

            try {
                  Log.d("entro linea 73","ruta "+ruta);
                final ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                Log.i("Entro a la linea 475","ruta "+ruta);
                final ContentProviderClient contentProvider = contentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(ruta);
                Log.i("Entro a la linea 477","ruta "+ruta);
                final byte[] fileInMemory = FileContent.getFileBytes(contentProvider, ruta);
                Log.i("Entro a la linea 479","ruta "+ruta);
                contentProvider.release();
                         Log.i("Entro a la linea 481","ruta "+ruta);
                // Repara el nombre del archivo (necesario para las fotos del carrete de la cámara, etc.)
                final String filename = FileContent.getValidFileName(contentResolver, ruta);

                final Option option = new QueryOption("@name.conflictBehavior", "fail");
                oneDriveClient
                        .getDrive()
                        .getItems(mItemId)
                        .getChildren()
                        .byId(filename)
                        .getContent()
                        .buildRequest(Collections.singletonList(option))
                        .put(fileInMemory,
                                new IProgressCallback<Item>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void success(final Item item) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        mensajeToast("Archivo subido "+item.name);

                                        //refresh();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void failure(final ClientException error) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        if (error.isError(OneDriveErrorCodes.NameAlreadyExists)) {
                                            mensajeToast("Hay conflicto con el nombre de otro archivo ");
                                        } else {
                                            mensajeToast(application.toString());
                                            mensajeToast(error.getMessage());
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void progress(final long current, final long max) {
                                        dialog.setProgress((int) current);
                                        dialog.setMax((int) max);
                                    }
                                });
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.toString());
                Log.i("Falla.......... 490","fallo ......."+e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    uploadFile.execute();
}
```

**Este es el error que se produce al intentar ejecutar la clase FileContent y el metodo getFileBytes**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor android.content.ContentProviderClient.openFile(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

este es el codigo del metodo

```
static byte[] getFileBytes(final ContentProviderClient contentProvider, final Uri data)
        throws IOException, RemoteException {
   final ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor = contentProvider.openFile(data, "r");
   if (descriptor == null) {
       throw new RuntimeException("\n" + "No se puede obtener el archivo ParcelFileDescriptor");
   }

   final int fileSize = (int) descriptor.getStatSize();
   return getFileBytes(contentProvider, data, 0, fileSize);
}
```

Quisiera como puedo recoger eso y subirlo los archivos que intento subir son .txt y .db y estan en la memoria interna del telefono.

Gracias si alguien puede ayudarme

Anexo capturas del telefono y pc 
[image: Captura del telefono se queda ahi]
[image: Captura en la pc]

Answer (score 0):

El valor del `ContentProvider` es nulo, al parecer es porque data no tiene valor:

```
final ContentProviderClient contentProvider = contentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(data.getData());
                    final byte[] fileInMemory = FileContent.getFileBytes(contentProvider, data.getData());
```

aunque tienes una validación, esta no se realizaría si alguno de los elementos no se cumple:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIMPLE_UPLOAD
            && data != null
            && data.getData() != null
            && data.getData().getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase(SCHEME_CONTENT))
```

asegura enviar correctamente el valor de `data`